# Redmine contex-menu and member deletion/modification failure

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, javascript, redmine

I'm using Redmine 0.9.3.stable (SQLite) on my Ubuntu 11.04.
It is all ok except for the context-menu and inability of removing the members from some project. Concerning the first problem, when I do the right click on some issue it opens a standard Firefox pop-up. Doing left-click on the issue simply doesn't "highlight" the issue. As for the second problem, the app just doesn't react at all to clicking on "delete/edit".

PS. I'm able to open up a context menu when I do that on the tracker of the public redmine project itself, so its not the browser issue.

**EDIT:** Issue solved long time ago by moving the redmine folder to its default location.